# array walk and replace in php or Javascript(phpjs)

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

This is my array:

```
$frndof = array(
        "name" => 'frnd_of_xyx',
        "id" => 001,
        "url" => 'example.com/frnd_of_xyx',
        "address" => array(
                "city" => 'NewZend',
                "zip" => '100450'));
$frndof1 = array(
        "name" => 'frnd_of_xyx1',
        "id" => 0011,
        "url" => 'example.com/frnd_of_xyx1',
        "frnds" => $frndof,
        "address" => array(
                "city" => 'NewZend1',
                "zip" => '100422'));
$a = array(
        array(
                "name" => 'xyx',
                "id" => 001,
                "url" => 'example.com/xyx',
                "address" => array(
                        "city" => 'cochin',
                        "zip" => '100450')),
        array(
                "name" => 'abc',
                "id" => 001,
                "url" => 'example.com/abc',
                "frnds" => $frndof1,
                "address" => array(
                        "city" => 'Bosco',
                        "zip" => '100450')),
        array(
                "name" => 'EFG',
                "id" => 001,
                "url" => 'example.com/EFG',
                "address" => array(
                        "city" => 'NY',
                        "zip" => '100450')));
```

I need a to replace the following array array_fig(1) with

```
[frnds] => Array
(
    [name] => frnd_of_xyx
    [id] => 1
    [url] =>example.com/frnd_of_xyx /* this is the unique key */
    [address] => Array
        (
            [city] => NewZend
            [zip] => 100450
        )
)
```

array_fig(2)

```
[frnds] => Array
(
    [name] => frnd_of_xyx
    [id] => 1
    [url] =>example.com/frnd_of_xyx /* this is the unique key */
    [address] => Array
        (
            [city] => NewZend_neww
            [zip] => 1004501212122
        )
)
```

The Key URL is the Unique key.  [frnds] array need to be replace with new [frnds] array.
ie How to find the parent key or array key with  " **[url]** "  key as the unique.

**Note:**this array is used for the XML generation so, these are the elements and attributes, so inner elements concepts

Comment: this array is used for the xml generation so, these are the elements and arrtibutes, so inner elements concepts

Comment: this array is an output of the json, and this output taken as the input to generte XML.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not used the key field as actual key in your array, the only available technique is linear search, i.e. iterate over the whole array with foreach.

```
$found=false;
foreach ($myarray as $key=>$val)
{
    if ($val['url']==$targetURL)
    {
        $myarray[$key]['address']=$newAddress;
        $found=true;
        break; 
    }
}
```

In Javascript, something like this

```
   var found=false;
   var key;
   for (key in myarray)
   {
       if (myarray[key]['url']==targetURL)
       {
             myarray[key]['address']=newAddress;
             found=true;
             break;
       }
   }
```

Comment: is this possible in Javascript?

Comment: @Paul Dixon: This array is used for xml generation.

Comment: @Paul Dixon: now it s replacing the address, but i need to replace the complete  [frnds] array which having the url

Comment: My example shows how to loop an object, and how to access its members - you should be able to take it from here!